# mysql query count

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I got the following mysql table

```
PrefixID + Prefix
001      + 110
005      + 550
005      + 550
005      + 550
005      + 550
```

and I want to turn it into the following table

```
PrefixID + Prefix + Count
001      + 110    + 1
005      + 550    + 4
```

Count is just the frequency of that particular prefix
How can i achieved that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause and a `COUNT()` aggregate:

```
SELECT `PrefixID`
     , `Prefix`
     , COUNT(1) AS `Count`
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY `PrefixID`, `Prefix`
```

From your sample data, it appears that the `Prefix` and `PrefixID` are dependent (one to one correspondence.) You may need to adjust the query, depending if you want to guarantee that either `PrefixID` or `Prefix` is unique in the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  PrefixID,
  MAX(Prefix) as  Prefix,
  Count(Prefix) as Count
FROM table
GROUP BY PrefixID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Select 
PrefixID, Prefix, count(Prefix)
from table
group by Prefix
```